# Can anybody explain me what is items[0].qty

Tags: c#-4.0

I tried this to Google it but didn't find.

```
items[0].qty 
items[0].price
```

What kind of variable is this and how to declare it and give values?

Comment: `items` is an array of some Object type. And in this type of Object, there are `price` and `qty` variables. And `items[0]` is referring to the first Object in the array.

Comment: but i still cannot explain how to declare int qty and decimal price in items array

Comment: Thanks very much i got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number within brackets represent the index of an array or collection. In other words, you're selecting the first item (index 0) of an array an then returning specific property value (i.e. Qty) It's like, in a table, "items" are all the rows, [0] is like row number and "Qty" is like a column name.